# In cmake, How to specific qt5 pacakge path

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

When I use following code:

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(ex ex.cc)
target_link_libraries(ex Qt5::Widgets Qt5::DBus)
```

I get:

```
Error:By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with any of the following names:
```

My qtbase path is in "/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/qtbase", and I have compile it, How to specific this path in `find_package`

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
        SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QT64_LOCATION})
        message(STATUS "QT find path: $ENV{QT64_LOCATION}")
    ELSE()
        SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QT_LOCATION})
        message(STATUS "QT find path: $ENV{QT_LOCATION}")
    ENDIF()
```

and add Paths to environment variables if it's not defined or hardcode it - CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\Qt\..\msvc2010\" or path to qmake in Linux
ie "/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/bin/qmake"

Also you can set default qt path

```
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf
```

set it to /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/bin/

Comment: I don't understand "QT64_LOCATION", is "/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/qtbase/bin" or "/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/qtbase"?

Comment: path to qmake and other executable objects, could be "/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/qtbase/bin"

Answer (score 0):

Set your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to your `Qt` folder. For example:

```
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2013")
```

The path could be different depending on your OS.